# How to use Mathematical Induction to prove $\frac{1}{1 \cdot 2} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n(n + 1)} = \frac{n}{n + 1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, induction

$$\frac{1}{1 \cdot 2} + \frac{1}{2\cdot 3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{n}{n+1}$$

What I have so far in the induction is:

$$\frac{1}{1 \cdot 2} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{k(k+1)} + \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)} = \frac{k}{k+1} + \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}$$

But I'm not sure where to go from there . . .

Comment: Hint : Put the fraction on the same denominator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a common denominator. Your last expression simplifies to $\dfrac{k^2 + 2k + 1}{(k+1)(k+2)}$. Now factor it.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{k}{k+1}+\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}=\frac{k(k+2)+1}{(k+1)(k+2)}=\frac{k+1}{k+2}$$