# How to solve $\frac{1}{1*2} + \frac{1}{2*3} + \frac{1}{3*4} + \dots + \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{n}{n+1}$

Tags: summation, induction

I am stuck on factoring out everything properly. I feel like I am combining these fractions wrong or something because I always have an extra 1.

edit: edit: I am still stuck. Math isn't working out, I am making a mess with the constant edits, I will stop editing and not touch this so people can review the question. Sorry

**a) Prove that P(1) is true**
$~$
$~$
$$\frac{1}{1*2} = \frac{1}{1+1} = \frac{1}{2}$$

**Show that P(k+1) is true as well** 
$$\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+1+1)} = \frac{k+1}{k+1+1} - \frac{k}{k+1}$$
$~~$
$$ = \frac{k+1}{k+1+1} \frac{k+1}{k+1} - \frac{k}{k+1} \frac{k+1+1}{k+1+1}$$
$~~$
$$ = \frac{(k+1)(k+1) - k(k+1+1)}{(k+1)(k+1+1)}$$
$~~$
$$ = \frac{(k+1)(k+1) - k(k+1+1)}{(k+1)(k+1+1)}$$
$~~$
$$ = \frac{(k+1)\bigg((k+1) - k(+1)\bigg)}{(k+1)(k+1+1)}$$
$~~$ 
$$ = \frac{k-k+1}{k+1+1} = \frac{1}{k+1+1} \neq \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+1+1)}$$

Comment: Try using ${1\over n(n+1)}=\frac1n-{1\over n+1}$

Comment: I did and I ended up with $\frac{2}{k+1+1}$ instead of $\frac{1}{k+1+1}$. I can add my work for that too

Comment: You'll have to show us that calculation before we can critique it.  As for the proof you posted, I don't really understand what you are trying to do.  Add some words, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Mathematical Induction to prove$\frac{1}{1 \cdot 2} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n(n + 1)} = \frac{n}{n + 1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580303/how-to-use-mathematical-induction-to-prove-frac11-cdot-2-frac12-cd)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/300460/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{k}{k+1}+\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)} = \frac{k(k+2)+1}{(k+1)(k+2)} = \frac{(k+1)(k+1)}{(k+1)(k+2)}.$$

---

Regarding your calculations, note that
$$ \frac{(k+1)(k+1) - k(k+1+1)}{(k+1)(k+1+1)} = \frac{k^2+2k+1-k^2-2k}{(k+1)(k+1+1)}=?$$

Comment: thank you, I see my problem now

Answer (score 3):

[You can use the trick of observing that it's a telescoping sum, or you just blast ahead with a proof by induction. I think you're asking about the second approach, so here's an answer.]

It's like any other induction proof. You get to assume "P(k)", which means you get to assume
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \frac{k}{k+1}.
$$
Now you want to show that "P(k+1)" is true: you want to show
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{i(i+1)} \overset{?}{=} \frac{k+1}{k+2}.
$$
Expand the left side:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{i(i+1)} + \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)} = \frac{k}{k+1} + \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)},
$$
where the last equality is by the inductive hypothesis. Now do some algebra:
$$
= \frac{k}{k+1} + \frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+2} = 1 - \frac{1}{k+2} = \frac{k+1}{k+2}.
$$
That completes the inductive step, and hence the proof.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

It is a telescoping sum since, for any $k>0$,
$$\frac 1{k(k+1)}=\frac 1k-\frac 1{k+1}.$$

Comment: I understand that part, but I think I am doing the math wrong in showing the equivalence when I am changing to greatest common denominators and combining the fractions.

Comment: Precidely, since you obtain a telescoping sum, *do not* combine the fractions!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

> $$\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\\\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\ldots+\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$